# Oracle sql : expression is of wrong type

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to write a PL/SQL to convert comma separated string into an array and iterate through that.

for that I created a datatype as follows:

```
"CODE_TABLE_TYPE" AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(500)
```

crated a function - `STR_TO_CODE_TABLE` to convert the comma separated string in to the table of CODE_TABLE_TYPE.

and the PL/SQL looks like this:

```
FOR DEP IN ( SELECT * FROM TABLE ( CAST( STR_TO_CODE_TABLE( IN_DES_AIRPORTS ) AS CODE_TABLE_TYPE ) ) ) LOOP

   SELECT * INTO RESULTS FROM MY_TABLE
   WHERE IN_ID = MY_TABLE.ID
   AND ( SELECT 1 FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE DEPARTURE LIKE '%' || DEP || '%' )= 1;

END LOOP;
```

But it gives an error saying "expression is of wrong type". But the datatype is varchar2.

Can anyone please suggest what's the possible cause for this. What should I do to avoid this issue?

Comment: `DEP` is **not** of type `varchar2` it's a record with a single column in it. You need to use `dep.column_value` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really missed that part. 

thanks again for the solution....

Comment: Also please read about bulk operations in oracle. loops with insert statements are so ancient.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Please write it as solution, with a code sample